# I have set this function in one loop but issue is only work in first tiime

Tags: c#

```
private static void SendMailTest()
{
    var dto = qEmail.Dequeue();    
    if (dto.Attachment != null && dto.Attachment.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dto.Attachment.Length; i++)
         {
            if (dto.Attachment[i] != null)
              {
                 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                 dto.Attachment[i].ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);                    
                 byte[] byteArr = ms.ToArray();
                 ms.Flush();
                  ms.Dispose();
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

not working this second time not copy in  dto.Attachment[i].ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);

Comment: what does `not working` mean? do you get an exception? is the `MemoryStream` empty? does the qeue have more than one element?

Comment: Step through it with the debugger

Comment: What is your exact error.

Comment: yes MemoryStream empty

Comment: dto.Attachment[i].ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);  first time attachment data copy to ms same function call 2nd time not working this

Comment: You already said that in your question. Have you stepped through your code with the debugger and checked if `dto.Attachment[i]` is not empty the second time around?

Comment: dto.Attachment[i] get data but not copy

Comment: On a `MemoryStream` calling `Flush` is redundant since `MemoryStream` is handled entirely within RAM. No data needs to be flushed. On a side note, whenever you create an instance of something that implements `IDisposable` implement it with a `using`-Block. In your case `using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream) { }`. That takes care automatically of all `Dispose` for you.

Comment: What is dto.Attachment[1].ContentStream.Length?

Comment: What is the namespace of Attachment?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is your problem, but I remember having an issue when the attachment was a PDF that had been produced by certain types of software, which did not like MemoryStream (for a reason I never understood - if I remember rightly it involved later versions of Crystal Reports).  However, I discovered it worked fine just as a Stream.  So I suggest you try something like:

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(dto.Attachment[i].ContentStream))
{
    byteArr = br.ReadBytes((int)dto.Attachment[i].ContentStream.Length);
}
```

This was a last resort for me, and depends on Length being reported accurately.  But it was better than nothing!